# Merging multiple rows based on condition in Power BI

Tags: merge, powerbi, dax

I have a table that looks like the one below.

*Table I have*

[image]

I want an output classifying the PART as either CLASS A or B. CLASS A and CLASS B should be created as two additional columns.

The conditions for classifications are:

-> IF Arrangement, Prefix and Range are the same, it will be classified as CLASS A and CLASS B, and the PART should be in both columns.

->
If the above condition is false, it will check the value in the TYPE column.
If the type column contains CLASS A, then the respective PART should be in the CLASS A column.
If the type column contains CLASS B, then the separate PART should be in the CLASS B column.

Here is the sample of the output I would need.

*Table I want*

[image]

So far, I have managed to get the below output but have not been able to merge the results into one row when the three columns are the same.

*Results I got till now*

[image: Results I got till now]

Sample Data

```
Arrangements    PREFIX  RANGE   PART    TYPE
ARR1    1XJ 1-100   191123  TRANSMISSION CLASS A
ARR1    1XJ 1-100   299123  TRANSMISSION CLASS B
ARR1    9TC 1-100   191123  TRANSMISSION CLASS A
ARR2    5TJ 101-120 288123  TRANSMISSION CLASS B
```

Comment: Please paste sample data as text

Comment: Thanks, David. I just added the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Query Editor (Transform Data), you can

- Group by `Arrangements`, `Prefix` and `Range` and use the **ALL** operation
- Then add Custom Columns with the formula below for `CLASS A`

  ```
  =try Table.SelectRows([Count], each Text.Contains([TYPE],"CLASS A"))[PART]{0} otherwise null
  ```

[image]

- Add another Custom Column for CLASS B with the obvious changes
- Delete the `Count` column

[image]

Comment: Hi Ron, Thanks..Can you help me to understand the code? What is [PART]{0}? Is it to select the 1st part in the group?

Comment: @subhro `Table.SelectRows([Count], each Text.Contains([TYPE],"CLASS A"))` returns the entire row in the Table in the `Count` column that contains `CLASS A` in the `TYPE` column.  `[PART` returns the `PART` column of that table. But it returns it as a `List` (albeit with just a single entry).  Using the `{0}` returns the first element of that `List` as text.  Experiment by removing the {0} and, in the added column, you will see `List` instead of a part number. If you float your cursor over the `List`, you'll see the contents down at the bottom. *M-Code doesn't make data type auto-conversions.*

Comment: This works great..Is there a way to add multiple OR conditions in a single statement? example - Table.SelectRows([Count], each Text.Contains([TYPE],"CLASS A" or "CLASS B"))

Comment: Thanks.. I tried the below codes, and it doesn't work. Any suggestions would be helpful.
1. try Table.SelectRows([Count], each List.Contains("FBP","TTBP",[USAGE]))[KITNUMBER]{0} otherwise null


2. try Table.SelectRows([Count], each Text([USAGE]="FBP" OR [USAGE]="TTBP))[KITNUMBER]{0} otherwise null

Comment: @subhro Without an example, hard for me to tell what you are doing, so you might be better off posting a new question. But your syntax is incorrect.  To do an `or`, the syntax would be something like `Text.Contains([TYPE],"CLASS A") or Text.Contains([TYPE],"CLASS B")`. Of course, you'd need to use the proper references.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in M Advanced Editor

```
Table.AddColumn(previousStepName, "Text After Delimiter", each Text.AfterDelimiter([TYPE], " "), type text)
```